# Nested Content Type in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, nested, content-type

as everybody can see i am new in drupal. So... i have a new site that has so much pages, and i had identified some blocks of information that are repeated in some of these pages . So... i had created my own content types trying to make them reutilizables. But my question is... Is any way to make a content type B that contents one ore more content types B? or i must create a content type for every page i have.

Other question i have is, a content type defines the structure(what fields are in) of an information part of a page, but how i then order and define where they must apear and how the must apear.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ur question is very basic I suggest you read a book first on drupal it will save you time. Make sure you read about views , blocks

Comment: Also, try to ask only one question per post.

Comment: Try the list of books here: 
http://drupal.org/books

Answer (score 1):

You might try the Entity Reference module: http://drupal.org/project/entityreference